# How can i get image from form and post it using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I want to get image information like size, type, name and stuff from HTML form and put it in a data var and post it using Ajax jQuery to Laravel but any time i get error like **Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**

HTML:

```
<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-parsley-validate novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">تصویر (اختیاری)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input id="image" name="image" type="file" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <button id="registerSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">
            افزودن
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('form').on('click', 'button.btn', function() {

var formdata = new FormData();
jQuery.each($('#image')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formdata.append('image', file);
});

var data = {
    first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    password: $("#password").val(),
    re_password: $("#re_password").val(),
    access_token: getCookie("access_token"),
    image: formdata,
    };

response = ajaxRequest("http://localhost:8000/api/admins/create", "POST", data);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made few changes to request body, added missing inputs and removed missing cookie variable.

"Illegal invocation" mistake not happens anymore.

Now you have to try it with your real API

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>

<form id="form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-parsley-validate novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-group">
    <input id="first_name">     <input id="email">
    <input id="password">       <input id="re_password">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">تصویر (اختیاری)</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input id="image" name="image" type="file" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <button id="registerSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light">
            افزودن
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('form').on('click', 'button.btn', function() {
    var formdata = new FormData();
    jQuery.each($('#image')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        formdata.append('image', file);
    });

    var userData = {
        first_name: $("#first_name").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        re_password: $("#re_password").val(),
        image: formdata,
    };

    response = $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        url:'http://localhost:8000/api/admins/create', 
        data: userData,
        processData: false
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks but it not worked